# Puppeteer meme scraper

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const memeArray = ['meme','memes','bestmemes','instamemes','funny','funnymemes','dankmemes','offensivememes','edgymemes','spicymemes','nichememes','memepage','funniestmemes','dank','memesdaily','jokes','memesrlife','memestar','memesquad','humor','lmao','igmemes','lol','memeaccount','memer','relatablememes','funnyposts','sillymemes','nichememe','memetime']

async function test() {
    // adjustment 1:
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null, args: ['--start-maximized'] });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('https://memes.com/search/?term=%23'+memeArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * memeArray.length)]);
    await page.waitForSelector('body > div.container.container-body > div.pt-5.js-post-tiles-container.js-search-feed.d-flex.flex-wrap.justify-content-between.post-tile-row')
    .then(async() =>
    {
      await page.$eval("body > div.container.container-body > div.pt-5.js-post-tiles-container.js-search-feed.d-flex.flex-wrap.justify-content-between.post-tile-row > a:nth-child(1)"), async el => await page.goto(el.href)
    });
}
```

Why am i receiving this error when i clearly provide a string. Do i need to add something else? Maybe im missing another parameter, im not really sure please help.

```
(node:18132) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Expected to get |string| or |function| as the first argument, but got "undefined" instead.
```

The error is on line 11:5

Comment: What you want to get from URL ?

Comment: What specifically you want to scrap?

Comment: @xMayank i want to scrape the image link

Comment: Here you are getting error because of this div. `<div class="pt-5 js-post-tiles-container js-search-feed d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between post-tile-row">
        </div>`

Comment: @xMayank how does that cause an error?

Comment: chrome dev shows different source and page source is different.

Comment: @xMayank I updated the path but still get the same error

Comment: @M00NL1G7 dude, typo, to be page.$eval('selector', () => {}) but you type page.$eval('selector'), ..

Comment: See the typo above, and, unfortunately, you cannot use `page` inside function argument of `page.$eval()` — it is executed in browser context where there is no `page` variable.